# Can a service defined on a module inject a service defined on a component declared by the same module

Tags: angular, angular2-di

Can a service defined on a module 'my' inject a service defined on a component declared by the module 'my'?

I've tested and it seems to be the case, so this question is mostly for the confirmation. So, I have this component that defines `ComboFeatureService`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'combo-feature',
    providers: [ComboFeatureService],
    template: '<div>I am feature</div>'
})
export class ComboFeature {
    constructor(comboService: ComboService) {
        comboService.report();
    }
}
```

Then I have a service that depends on `ComboFeatureService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComboService {
    constructor(public comboFeature: ComboFeatureService) {

    }
```

And both the component and the service are defined on the **same** module:

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [ComboService],
    declarations: [ComboFeature],
    exports: [ComboFeature]
})
export class ComboModule {
```

Is my understanding correct that even they are both defined on the same module, `ComboService` won't be able to access to `ComboFeatureService`?

If that's the case, then as I understand component injector **is not** a child of root injector, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the services are defined on the same module or not (unless this is lazy loaded module), module `providers` belong to root injector.

In order to do that, both providers should be defined on current injector:

```
@Component({
    ...
    providers: [ComboService, ComboFeatureService]
})
export class ComboFeature {
    constructor(comboService: ComboService) { ... }
```

Alternatively, `ComboFeatureService` can be injected as optional, this will allow `ComboService` to use `ComboFeatureService` from current injector (or nothing if there is none):

```
@Injectable()
export class ComboService {
    constructor(Optional() public comboFeature: ComboFeatureService) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

Providers are looked up from the component where they are required. If not found provider search continues at the parent until the root injector (providers added to `@NgModule(...)` of non-lazy loaded modules ) is reached.

This means your service provided at the module can't inject a service provided by a component, because it would require from the root injector to search towards the leafs, which won't happen. Only the other way around works. Dependencies need to be provided at the same or a higher level.